# force error when parsing "01" from string to number in rust

Tags: string, parsing, rust, type-conversion, numbers

I've have a string like this

"32" or "28", "01", "001"

and I want to parse them to a number.
However it should not parse a string that starts with 0.

Currently, I'm doing this

```
let num = str.parse().unwrap_or(-1);
```

With this implementation it converts "01" to 1 but I want to force -1 when the string stars with 0.

Comment: Did you tried using `str::starts_with`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments - you could use this:

```rust
let num = if s.len() > 1 && s.starts_with('0') {
    -1
} else {
    s.parse().unwrap_or(-1)
};
```

Comment: "0" is ok, I only want to return -1 when it's something like this "00" or "01"

Comment: just add `s != "0" &&` to the condition

Comment: @cafce25 yeah it works but I wish there was a more elegant solution

Comment: If you're willing to add a dependency you cold use regex crate `Regex::new(r"^0\d+").unwrap().is_match(s)`